# How to loop through a dataframe and construct a string out of the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Tom', 'Mary', 'Phil', 'Harry'], 
                  'age': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 
                 'credits':[4,6,2,3,4]})
```

I want to create an SQL INSERT statement out of these values:

```
INSERT INTO credits_table VALUES ('John', 20, 4)
INSERT INTO credits_table VALUES ('Tom', 30, 6)
INSERT INTO credits_table VALUES ('Mary', 40, 2)
INSERT INTO credits_table VALUES ('Phil', 50, 3)
INSERT INTO credits_table VALUES ('Harry', 60, 4)
```

To achieve this, I'm trying to the below: looping through each of the dataframe columns and generate the INSERT INTO statements:

```
for i in df.index:
    print ('INSERT INTO credits VALUES (' + df.loc[i,'name'] + ','+ df.loc[i,'age'] + ','+df.loc[i,'credits']+ +')')
```

But something is wrong and it just keeps failing again and again. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Use this line inside the loop `print ('INSERT INTO credits VALUES ({},{},{})'.format(df.loc[i,'name'], df.loc[i,'age'],df.loc[i,'credits']))`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df.index:
    print ('INSERT INTO credits VALUES (\'{}\', {}, {})'.format(df.loc[i,'name'], df.loc[i,'age'], df.loc[i,'credits']))
```

If you want to insert it to sql consider using - `pandas.to_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the values that you are extracting from each raw to string, for being able to concatenate them with the sql textual statement:

```
for i in df.index:
    print ('INSERT INTO credits VALUES (' + str(df.loc[i,'name']) + ',' + str(df.loc[i,'age']) + ',' + str(df.loc[i,'credits']) +')')
```

(note that you have double + signs at the end of the line)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uufma.png)